# Partially melt hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df that I want to look like df2.

```
yesterday = datetime.datetime.today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[['A','B'],['1','2']], names=['letter','number'])
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=yesterday, periods=2, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=idx, data=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

letter                      A     B   
number                      1  2  1  2
2019-09-26 07:45:49.659873  1  2  3  4
2019-09-26 08:45:49.659873  5  6  7  8

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['letter', '1', '2'], index=idx.append(idx), data=[['A',1,2],['A',5,6],['B',3,4],['B',7,8]])

                           letter  1  2
2019-09-26 07:45:49.659873      A  1  2
2019-09-26 08:45:49.659873      A  5  6
2019-09-26 07:45:49.659873      B  3  4
2019-09-26 08:45:49.659873      B  7  8
```

So it's sort of like a melt, or reset_index but I haven't found the magic combination to do this on a much larger dataframe in practice. I want to change level 0 of the columns into an unpivoted column, but leave level 1 unchanged.

Comment: Is it not `df.stack(0)`?

Comment: agreed with @QuangHoang  simple `stack()` with `.reset_index(1)` should do it: `df.stack(0).reset_index(1).rename_axis(None,axis=1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang That's almost it, but that pushes the melted column into the index. Maybe I could move the index in as a column...

Comment: syzygy: you can see @anky_91's comment.